# List all btrfs filesystems and subvolumes in shell

Tags: shell, btrfs

Is there a convenient way to get information on all **btrfs** filesystems **subvolumes** without resorting to C, i.e. in **POSIX shell** ?

`/sys/fs/btrfs` contains info only on filesystems, nothing on subvolumes, so currently i end up mounting all filesystems in a temp folder,  scanning them with `btrfs subvol list`, then parsing the resulting output.
Needless to say, that is fairly ugly.

This is with a **3.16.x** kernel and **btrfs-progs v3.14.1** (from stock Ubuntu 14.10).

Below is the (ugly) script I'm currently using. I know I could get the info I need using pure C, and that's probably what I'll end up doing, but I was wondering if there was a simpler, more elegant way.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in /sys/fs/btrfs/*[!features]; do 

  device="/dev/$(basename $i/devices/*)"
  mountpoint=/var/lib/btrfs/tmp/mnt/$(basename "$i")

  [ -d "$mountpoint" ] || mkdir "$mountpoint"

  grep -qs $mountpoint /proc/mounts
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && mount -v "$device" "$mountpoint"

  while read -r subvol; do
    # whatever you want
  done < <(btrfs subvolume list "$mountpoint")

  umount $mountpoint
  rmdir $mountpoint
done
```

Comment: Did you end up writing a C program for this? I'm sure other people would find it useful if you're willing to share.

Comment: If fails for me: ``line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `done'`` and ``line 15: `  done < <(btrfs subvolume list "$mountpoint")'``

Answer (score 6):

`/sys/fs/btrfs` does't list all btrfs filesystem (e.g not mounted one), tested on Debian / Ubuntu (4.14.0-1 / 4.10.0-42).
I would use btrfs progs to search them:

```
btrfs filesystem show | awk '/ path /{print $NF}'
```

And since btrfs progs can list subvolumes only of mounted fs, your script is not far from what I would use:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t btdev < <(sudo btrfs filesystem show | awk '/ path /{print $NF}' )

for i in "${btdev[@]}"; do 

  device="${i}"
  mountpoint=/var/lib/btrfs/tmp/mnt/$(basename "$i")

  [ -d "$mountpoint" ] || mkdir "$mountpoint"

  grep -qs $mountpoint /proc/mounts
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && mount -v "$device" "$mountpoint"

  while read -r subvol; do
    # whatever you want
  done < <(btrfs subvolume list "$mountpoint")

  umount $mountpoint
  rmdir $mountpoint
done
```

Not tested against multi-device filesystem (raid-0/1/10/5/6)

Comment: Fails for me: ``line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `done'`` and ``line 17: `  done < <(btrfs subvolume list "$mountpoint")'``

Comment: @Smeterlink that's probably because your script got interpreted by another `sh` than `bash`, try `chmod +x the-script.sh && ./the-script.sh` or worst-case `bash the-script.sh`

Comment: I have to use `sudo` to do see some outpur from commands like: `btrfs filesystem show <path>`.  _Maybe_??