# How to distinguish between a directory and a subvolume?

Tags: mount, btrfs, snapper

In GNU/Linux **how is the best way to tell the difference between a directory and a btrfs subvolume**?

I know they are suppose to look the same, and that's cool.  But for maintenance purposes, when I look at a directory, I want to know if its just a directory, or if its instead a subvolume.  *(For that matter it would also be nice to know if it's mounted or not, and if so how and from where.)*

**Purpose:** I want to revise how my sub-volumes are structured, as suggested for example [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Snapper).  I need a way to see what I'm doing, in order to check what I'm doing. Thanks.  :-)

---

**What I've looked at:**

The output of **`ls -d`** or **`tree -d`** show folders, but don't distinguish between **directories** and **btrfs subvolumes**.  Using `ls -l` they in-fact look identical.

Even **`ls --classify`** and **`ls --file-type`** don't seem to clarify this distinction.

---

**Possible solution:**

I found that I could check the inode number of a folder, and if it was **256** that would say it's a subvolume.  (Refs [1](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Trees), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908149/how-to-test-if-location-is-a-btrfs-subvolume), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345471/btrfs-same-inode-number))

---

**So is using inode=256 the best heuristic to distinguish between directories and subvolumes?**  (I'm assuming that in some underlying file system there might be another reason for an inode to be =256.   So to do a definitive check, you would also have to be sure the directory in question was part of a btrfs file system.)

**Another approach** might be via the command `btrfs subversion list .` and then parsing the output.  You would have to add to this `mount | grep /\`, or something like that to handle the root mount of a btrfs disk, disks, partition or partitions as the case may be.

---

**Future:**  I think it would be great if there was some new option on **`ls`** that would give information about sub-volumes and mount points, possibly in a format similar to how soft links are displayed, i.e.

```
$ ls --show-mounts
/ <-- mounted from /dev/sdc
.snapshots <-- subvolume of /
shapshot <-- subvolume of .snapshots mounted to it's folder /2
```

---

**Background:**

- Directories and subvolumes are vastly different things to manage.
- You can't use `rmdir` or  `rm -rf` to remove a subvolume, but instead must use `btrfs subvolume delete`.
- And you can't hard link directories or files unless you are within one specific subvolume.
- Subvolumes appear as being auto-mounted, although they can also be mounted manually to different mount points.
- If you use **snapper** or take snapshots, snapshots are actually subvolumes, at least a special type of subvolume.

  **For example,** your root tree might look partly like this:

  ```
  /  
  /.snapshots  
  /.snapshots/1  
  /.snapshots/1/snapshot  
  /.snapshots/2  
  /.snapshots/2/snapshot  
  ...
  ```

  Only `/1` and `/2` are normal directories here, while `/`, `/.snapshots`, and `/snapshot` appear to be btrfs subvolumes.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193619/list-all-btrfs-filesystems-and-subvolumes-in-shell

Comment: I can't investigate right now, but I'm wondering if `findmnt` might be useful here.

Answer (score 5):

```
btrfs subvolume show /directory/in/question
```

Most likely you need `sudo`. The command will succeed if it's a subvolume; it will fail otherwise. You can redirect output to `/dev/null` and rely solely on the exit status.

This will test every directory available in the directory tree:

```
sudo find / -type d -exec sh -c '
   for d do
      btrfs subvolume show "$d" >/dev/null 2>&1 && printf "%s\n" "$d"
   done' find-sh {} +
```

You may want to exclude paths that are beyond suspicion. The following code excludes `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev`:

```
sudo find / -type d \( \
     \( -path /proc -prune \) -o \
     \( -path /sys -prune \) -o \
     \( -path /dev -prune \) -o \
     \( -exec sh -c '
        for d do
           btrfs subvolume show "$d" >/dev/null 2>&1 && printf "%s\n" "$d"
        done
     ' find-sh {} + \) \)
```

---

Related: [How to determine which subvolume a directory/file is on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631561/108618)

Answer (score 4):

The `st_dev` field returned by `stat(2)`, called ID of device containing
file, is different across BTRFS subvolumes as well as across
filesystems.  Using the command line, that is

```
if [ btrfs != "$(findmnt -noFSTYPE --target=.)" ]
then
    echo "not btrfs"
elif findmnt . >/dev/null
then
    echo "btrfs mountpoint"
elif [ "$(stat -c%d .)" -ne "$(stat -c%d ..)" ]
then
    echo "btrfs subvolume"
else
    echo "btrfs directory"
fi
```

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't work.   Shows what 'device', not if the device is a btrfs, or if btrfs subvolume.

Comment: Compare `st_dev` against that of the parent directory. They're different for subvolumes. See my edit.