# How to determine which subvolume a directory/file is on?

Tags: btrfs

I want to determine which subvolume a file or directory is on. For example, if I have a subvolume mount at `/mnt/btrfs-subvol` and a directory `/mnt/btrfs-subvol/some/dir` and I run `something /mnt/btrfs-subvol/some/dir` it returns `btrfs-subvol`.

The best I can think to do is to walk back, testing each directory with `stat` as I go for an inode of 256, but I can't imagine that is the only way of doing this. Or maybe run maybe

```
until btrfs sub show `pwd`; cd ..;done; echo `pwd`
```

But I feel there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use `stat` (which is not required by POSIX) and it's rich enough with options then this command:

```
stat --format=%m /mnt/btrfs-subvol/some/dir
```

will show you what you want. Note `dir` can be any type of [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), not necessarily a directory.

Notes:

- The manual says `%m` denotes the mountpoint; this is somewhat misleading in case of Btrfs. My tests in Kubuntu 18.04.5 LTS indicate that even if `/mnt/btrfs-subvol/` is not an explicit mountpoint (i.e. `mount whatever /mnt/btrfs-subvol/` never happened) but it's a subvolume (inside a subvolume explicitly mounted as `/` or `/mnt/`) then the command will treat it as a mountpoint. It seems this is what you want anyway.
- The output is a path valid in the directory structure in the OS, not in the Btrfs directory (and subvolumes) tree on the device (if you're not sure what the difference is then read [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1396245/432690) and my answer there). Again it seems this behavior is what you want.
- The command is valid for filesystems other than Btrfs (e.g. `stat --format=%m /dev/null` prints `/dev` in my Kubuntu). Obviously in general other filesystems have no concept of subvolumes. Maybe you should check first if the file you're after lives in a Btrfs filesystem:

  ```
  stat --file-system --format=%T /mnt/btrfs-subvol/some/dir
  ```

  If you see `btrfs` then proceed with the main command to find the subvolume. Unfortunately a single invocation of `stat` cannot print both pieces of information (you go either with `--file-system` or without).
- The above conclusion means you need to run `stat` two times. There is no guarantee they will see the same `dir` under the path `/mnt/btrfs-subvol/some/dir`. What if some (un)mounting happens in between? Compare [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). In Linux I am able to reliably run two `stat`s on the same file without TOCTOU by using a file descriptor:

  ```
  ( stat --dereference --file-system --format=%T /proc/self/fd/3
    stat --dereference --format=%m /proc/self/fd/3 ) 3</mnt/btrfs-subvol/some/dir
  ```

  <sup>Note if `dir` itself is a symlink, the commands will follow it.</sup>

  Still you probably want to know the subvolume in order to do something with it later. You get it as a path anyway. Before you use it the situation may change and TOCTOU may hit you.

  If you are pretty sure the relevant paths don't change their meaning without your consent then just work with `stat`s and their results in a straightforward way.
- In my tests `stat --file-system …` behaves like `stat --file-system --dereference …`. This means `stat`s with and without `--file-system` (both without explicit `--dereference`) may yield inconsistent results if the target file is a symlink.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I'm looking for. As you inferred, this is information that will be fed to another part of a script. I hadn't considered just looking for the mount point. I feel silly now. For my use, symlinks aren't an issue.